# pymongo method find_one work but find method doesn't

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying a simple query expression:

```
df = db.persons.find_one({"name.first": "victor"})
```

That's work fine. When I try the same query using `find` method the return is empty.

```
df = db.persons.find({"name.first":"victor"})
```

My objective is a query expression with 2 arguments `"name.first" : "victor"` and `"name.last":"perdensen"`. I also tried `$and`operator.

```
df = db.persons.find({"$and": [{"name.first": "victor"}, {"name.last": "pedersen"}]})
```

Both queries using compass I had no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `find_one()` returns a `dict` if data is available, `find()` returns an iterator since there may be more than one json document.

So if you get a result of a query with `find_one()`, you will also get a result with `find()` but this time, you have to access it in a for loop.

```
df = db.persons.find({"name.first": "victor"})
for df1 in df:
    print(df1) # here you get the result
```

Comment: Thank you ! I forgot think about the type of return of method find. Novice things.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also do this:

```
df = list(db.persons.find({"name.first": "victor"}))
```